# R & dplyr: aggregate and build sum variables

Tags: r, dplyr

This question builds on another question I previously asked. Given the MWE below:

```
test <- as.data.table(data.frame(event_id = c("A","B","A","A","B"),
                                 income = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                                 location = c("PlaceX","PlaceY","PlaceX","PlaceX","PlaceY")))

test
   event_id income location
1:        A      1   PlaceX
2:        B      2   PlaceY
3:        A      3   PlaceX
4:        A      4   PlaceX
5:        B      5   PlaceY
```

How would I get:

```
  event_id mean_inc    loc_PlaceX    loc_PlaceY
    (fctr)   (fctr)     (numeric)     (numeric)
1        A 2.666667             3             0
2        B 3.500000             0             2
```

What I have so far:

```
test %>%
  group_by(event_id, location) %>%
  summarise(mean_inc = mean(income))

Source: local data table [2 x 3]
Groups: event_id

  event_id location mean_inc
    (fctr)   (fctr)    (dbl)
1        A   PlaceX 2.666667
2        B   PlaceY 3.500000
```

Please note I have about 10 columns that I'd have to break down like I am trying to do with the `location` column above. Also, there are millions of rows.

Comment: Maybe read a tutorial on dplyr and tidyr.

Comment: @Frank that's helpful, thanks

Comment: you can try this `test %>%
  group_by(event_id, location) %>%
  summarise(mean_inc = mean(income), count = n())` It will give you the count of location in 1 column, you can then `reshape` the results for the required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP showed a `data.table`, it can be done with `data.table` methods

```
test[, mean_inc := mean(income), event_id]
dcast(test, event_id+mean_inc~location, value.var="income", length)
#     event_id mean_inc PlaceX PlaceY
#1:        A 2.666667      3      0
#2:        B 3.500000      0      2
```